# PL/SQL: Finding the average of a substraction of two values

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

Essentially, part of my function is to find the average of a local variable called Days_Stayed, which is the subtraction of the Departure_Date and the Arrival_Date. The REGISTRATION table only stores the date the person arrives and leaves, not the time stayed itself.

My problem is that this occurs when a client has stayed more than one time, thus there are multiple Departure_Dates and Arrival_Dates. The average is composed of the sum of the results of each of those subtractions, if that makes sense.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
    (p_CustomerCode CHAR)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS 
    v_Output VARCHAR2(100);
    Days_Stayed DATE;
BEGIN
        --SELECT STATEMENT FROM REGISTRATION TABLE--
        IF Registration_Status = 'R' THEN
            Days_Stayed = Departure_Date - Arrival_Date;
            v_Output := (SELECT TO_CHAR(AVG(Days_Stayed), 'Day') 
                         FROM REGISTRATION WHERE Customer_Code = p_CustomerCode), 
                         --other columns
```

If anyone can give me a hand with this problem it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it should just be:

```
v_Output := (SELECT TO_CHAR(AVG(Departure_Date - Arrival_Date), 'Day') 
                         FROM REGISTRATION WHERE Customer_Code = p_CustomerCode)
```

Just put the subtraction inside the select statement. 
Does that work?

Comment: i will check it out, but will it not freak out if there are multiple records for departure and arrival? (say if the customer stayed multiple times)

Comment: No the average function will sum up the column and then divide by the amount of rows for you. Here is an example: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Database/Oracle_Aggregate_Function/00__Oracle_AVG.htm

Answer (score 0):

To me, it sounds like `SUM` / `COUNT`, e.g.

```
SQL> with registration (id, departure_date, arrival_date) as
  2    (select 1, date '2019-09-20', date '2019-09-17' from dual union all -- 3 days
  3     select 1, date '2019-08-13', date '2019-08-11' from dual union all -- 2 days
  4     select 1, date '2019-08-08', date '2019-08-01' from dual union all -- 7 days
  5     --
  6     select 2, date '2019-07-20', date '2019-07-19' from dual union all -- 1 day
  7     --
  8     select 3, date '2019-08-27', date '2019-08-25' from dual union all -- 2 days
  9     select 3, date '2019-08-14', date '2019-08-12' from dual           -- 2 days
 10    )
 11  select id,
 12         sum(departure_date - arrival_date) / count(*) avg_days_stayed
 13  from registration
 14  group by id;

        ID AVG_DAYS_STAYED
---------- ---------------
         1               4
         2               1
         3               2

SQL>
```

Why? Your code subtracts departure and arrival date (single values), so - how would you select an average of one value? Perhaps you meant to use a loop (through each person) or something else, but - the above query might push you to the right direction, i.e. no loop, use single query.